# PHP - Function with foreach slowing down site

Tags: php, api

I'm working on a project that connects to an external API. I have already made the connection and I've implemented several functions to retrieve the data, that's all working fine.

The following function however, works exactly like it should, only it slows down my website significantly ( 25 seconds + ).

Is this because of the nested foreach loop? And what can i do to refactor the code?

```
/**
 * @param $acti
 */
function getBijeenkomstenFromAct ($acti) {
    $acties = array();
    foreach ($acti as $act) {
        $bijeenkomsten = $this->getBijeenkomstenFromID($act['id']);
        if (in_array('Doorlopende activiteit', $act['type'])) {
            foreach ($bijeenkomsten as $bijeenkomst) {
                $acties[] = array(
                    'id'         => $act['id'],
                    'Naam'       => $act['titel'],
                    'interval'   => $act['interval'],
                    'activiteit' => $bijeenkomst['activiteit'],
                    'datum'      => $bijeenkomst['datum']
                );
            }
        } else {
            $acties[] = array (
                'id'            => $act['id'],
                'type'          => $act['type'],
                'activiteit'    => $act['titel'],
                'interval'      => $act['interval'],
                'dag'           => $act['dag'],
                'starttijd'     => $act['starttijd'],
                'eindtijd'      => $act['eindtijd']

            );
        }
    }
    return $acties;
}
```

The function "getBijeenkomstenfromID" is working fine and on it's own not slow at all. Just to be sure, here is the function:

```
/**
 * @param $activitieitID
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 */
public function getBijeenkomstenFromID($activitieitID) {
    $options = array(
        //'datumVan'      => date('Y-m-d'),
        'activiteit'    => array (
            'activiteit'    => $activitieitID
        ),
        'limit'     => 5,
        'datumVan'  => date(("Y-m-d"))
    );
    $bijeenkomsten = $this->webservice->activiteitBijeenkomstOverzicht($this->api_key, $options);

    return $bijeenkomsten;
}
```

Comment: How many times are you going through the loop?  Even if the API call only takes half a second each time (which you might consider "not slow at all"), then it only takes 50 loops to hit 25 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling on the API from within the first foreach loop, which is not efficient.

Every time you do this:

```
$bijeenkomsten = $this->getBijeenkomstenFromID($act['id']);
```

you're adding a lot of "dead" time to your script since you have to put on with network latency, the time you need to allow for the API to actually do the work and transmit it back to you. Even though this may be quick (let's say 100ms total), if your first foreach loop iterates 100 times, you already have accumulated 10 seconds of waiting, and that's before **getBijeenkomstenFromAct ($acti)** has done any real processing.

The best practice here would be to split this if possible. My suggestion:

Make **getBijeenkomstenFromID($activitieitID)** run asynchronously on its own for all the IDs you need to lookup in the API. The key here is for it to run as a separate process and then have it pass the array it constructs to **getBijeenkomstenFromAct** so that it can loop and process it happily.

So yes, basically I'm suggestion that you orchestrate your process backwards for efficiency's sake

Comment: Right. This looks like the way to go. Now just need to figurout how to make it run async.

Comment: you may use curl_multi or, a more "nuclear" approach would be to run the whole getBijeenkomstenFromID function before even invoking the getBijeenkomstenFromAct function... 

depending on what the API does and how often the information for each ID changes, you may want to have a scheduled daily or hourly process (triggered, for example, with cron) and have it run in the background.

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past, and what I eventually ended up doing was:

download all data from the external source (irrelevant as it may be for this purpose, I was downloading weather information for all airports in the world, which is updated hourly), so I had a function that was triggered every hour on the hour to download all the (thousands of) airports at once, which took around half a minute and store them in a database.

afterwards, when needed, I looped through my "local" copy, which was blazing fast and users experienced less than a second waiting

Comment: I made a function  that retrieves everything I need and stores it in the database. Then I placed it in a separate file and made a cronjob that runs that file every hour. Function checks if there is anything in the database already, if not. The data gets pulled from the API. My main file now pulls it's data directly from the database and that saved me 20 to 25 seconds. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Look into **curl_multi**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

It will let you call an external API asynchronously and process the returns all at once.  Be aware that APIs often have their own limitations on asynchronous calls, and common sense dictates that you probably shouldn't be hammering a website with 200 separate calls.  But if your number of calls is under a dozen or two (and the API allows it), curl_multi will do nicely.